# Initialize QByteArray avoiding [-Wnarrowing]

Tags: c++, qt, casting, char

I am on an architecture where `char` is interpreted as `signed` by default.

I construct a `char array` similar as mentioned in the [Qt5 documentation for QByteArray](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#fromRawData):

```
const char char_buffer[] = {
    0xFF, 0x00, 0x03
};
```

When I later call `QByteArray::fromRawData(char_buffer)` respectively `QByteArray(char_buffer)`, the compiler will complain:

```
error: narrowing conversion of ‘255’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

(There is no `unsigned char *` parameter overload for `fromRawData()`)

## Solutions:

Whenever I have to interact with one of the in-built function, I cast an `unsigned char *`.

```
const char uchar_buffer[] = {
    0xFF, 0x00, 0x03
}; 
QByteArray::fromRawData(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(uchar_buffer), sizeof(uchar_buffer))
```

## Question:

Did I oversee any easier/straight forward solution without casting (and keeping the warning for narrowing)?

Comment: Declare the array as unsigned char and cast it when interacting with qt ?

Comment: @AndreiAndrey I did this (updated the question with a more smplier casting now). Can you think of how to avoid casting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution of casting the `unsigned char *` whenever interacting with a Qt function expecting a `char *` is okay.

## An alternative to casting

Use the compiler flag `-funsigned-char` to make the compiler use `unsigned char` by default.

With .pro:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -funsigned-char
```

With CMake:

```
set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-funsigned-char")
```

## The proper solution

The initial issue is how the `char_buffer` is initialised. [Integer literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) (e.g. 0xFF) are from type integer. It's best to use [character literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) in the first place, e.g.,

```
const char char_buffer[] = {
    '\xFF', '\x00', '\x03'
};
```

Comment: When initializing a `char` array use char literals. I consider the original code to be smelly in that regard (which is what the warning is about).

Comment: @Darklighter I agree, but that's exactly what **Alternative 1** is about.

Comment: I know, I just wanted to state my opinion that it’s not really an alternative but the right way™.

Comment: Okay, got you @Darklighter . In my case, I wrote code based on the provided example and would rather avoid changing now to char literals all over the place. Anyhow, I agree and will change the answer, although these char literals look really ugly.